# Store session variable in action filter or static method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

Right now I am using a session variable to store a boolean value which I then use in my views.  I know that HttpContext.Session[] variables are static, but does that mean I need to store them in a static method, or can I keep them in my action filter and call them directly from there?

**Controller:**

```
public class AuthorizationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        // If not authorized, redirect to login page
        if (true)
        {
            authorized = false;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Session["authorized"] = authorized;


            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("https://www.website.com");
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Session["authorized"] = authorized;
        }
...
```

**View:**

```
@{var authorized = (bool)Session["authorized"];}
@if (authorized != null)
{
    if (authorized == true)
    {
        <li><a href="/">Download</a></li>
    }  
}
```

Should I be storing my session variables in static methods like below and calling them, instead of what I do above?

```
    public static bool Authorized(){
        return (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["authorized"];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call `Session` variable like you did with no problems.

By the way,

`@{var authorized = (bool)Session["authorized"];}`

would throw an exception if `Session["authorized"] == null`.

**UPDATE**:

Common utility functions are often made static, because they're easy to use that way (don't need to create class instance each time you want to use functionality).

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` object (gets the same `HttpSessionState` object as wrapped by `System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext`) is available for the current HTTP request from anywhere in your application. It does not need to specifically belong to a static method. It could if you wanted to, but it does not have to.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the catch.  Didn't even notice that.  The rest of the interwebs has the session variable stored in a static method.  Any reason why in this case that's not necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the correct way. You should use the Session variable directly. No need to use a Static method. Session variables are available for that user session. They are not static variable(i.e. Class level variables)

Comment: I love to hear that I'm correct :), but could you maybe expound as to why I don't need to put it in a static method?

Comment: I just updated the answer. There is not point in returning Session variable from a static method.